# Pandas.Series в ячейке

Tags: pandas

Есть объект test типа `pandas.core.series.Series` в каждой ячейке которого `list`.

Я трансформирую серию через
`test=pd.DataFrame(test)`
и получаю стандартный Датафрейм, но вот тип данных в ячейках становится `pandas.core.series.Series`.

Хотелось бы разобраться почему так выходит и как это победить получив на выходе датафрейм в ячейках которого все те же списки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спрошу, сам и отвечу. Потому что надо использовать в данном случае не `pd.DataFrame(test)`, а `test.to_frame()`